# Why can't I open Dropbox via Launchpad?

Tags: macos, launchpad, dropbox

The Dropbox app is shown in Launchpad. When I click on it's icon to launch it nothing happens and I return to my browser.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 5):

Dropbox has no "Window" to speak of. Everything it does takes place either:

1. On Dropbox.com
2. Via the Finder in the configured Dropbox folder (NB: right click a file in the Dropbox folder), simply named 'Dropbox' in your home directory by default. Or;
3. In the MenuBar

[image: Dropbox Menubar Icon]

Per [Dropbox's Documentation](http://www.dropbox.com/help/146), the primary states will be a blue icon with circular arrows indicating a file is synchronizing, or the green checkmark icon like above, indicating everything is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

There is no dropbox app - it runs in the background - There is an icon on the menu bar.

Comment: There is a Dropbox app (/Applications/Dropbox.app), but it has no visible window (just the menu bar icon).